# Fear about people getting better than the leader

Tags: management, leadership

I am a senior software engineer who is starting with leading.

I was following a course on Udemy where they say,

> "Don't be afraid that your reports get better than you. You should encourage that! Nobody got fired because their reports got better than their leader."

Is that actually true? What if I am not good at leading, I get worse in programming because of not practicing it, and then they fire me because I am more expensive than the cheaper young guys who will get better than me?

It seems to me like a general problem that many people had to struggle with before. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: So work on being a good leader. And if your mentoring makes them all better programmers than you currently are, well, you are in a great place.

Comment: A good leader is someone I am willing to follow.  If you're constantly checking who is best, you're not someone I would want to follow.

Comment: Effective leaders are worth more than effective programmers as a whole - it is easier to find technical skill than people skills. Everyone knows that effective leadership can take teams to new levels, but it's very hard to find good management.

Answer (score 21):

As a manager you don't need to be good at what your reports do. I have a great manager right now and he openly admits that he has no clue about what we are doing every day. Yet he is doing a great job at what his actual responsibilities as a manager are: Regulating our workloads, removing obstacles, supporting our ideas, enabling our personal growth, having our backs in difficult situations and so on.

So what would a good manager do if one of their reports also shows leadership potential?

- Give them leadership responsibility below them. Like letting them lead a sub-team, giving them a project to manage or putting them in charge of apprentices, trainees or interns.
- Recommend them for a management position somewhere else in the company.
- Apply for a higher management position themselves and recommend their report as their successor for their current position.

Comment: Absoloutely 100%.  The first mistake most people make is assume the manager needs to be the best version of the people reporting to them.  Nothing is further from the truth.  They are different jobs with different skills & responsibilties.  I'd go as far to say that while a manager who knows the job can be empathethic and helpful sometimes, mostly it's a pain because they just can't resist solving the problem and then nagging their people to do the job the way they would.

Answer (score 12):

This is not an uncommon feeling in those who are new to leading. You have built a career on being good at something and to lead a team you feel like you need to be the best at that thing. In fact, to lead a team you need to be good at leading, which is an entirely different set of skills.

I started my career as a programmer, moved in to senior roles and team leader roles and now I'm a department manager. **Every team member I have working for me is better at their roles than I am**, otherwise why would I employ them? I may as well do it myself (volume of work notwithstanding). It is an odd thing to have to get used to and I've worked with other people new to leadership roles who feel exactly this way. That being said, in my opinion my role is to get the best of my team, to help them develop in to the best versions of themselves they can be, without exception. If I'm blocking them so they don't become "better" than me, then I am doing them and my employer a huge disservice. My employer pays me to get the best work from the team we can collectively do. That won't happen unless I allow and actively help and encourage team members to develop and grow.

**tl;dr**

You should focus on becoming the best leader you can be, while encouraging the team to be the best they can be. That is the mark of a successful leader.

Answer (score 7):

I think the other answers are good but I have two things that I think are useful to add.

Firstly, if management doesn't work out for whatever reason, I don't think that returning to coding is out of the question. I did exactly that in my first management role. I was managing a team in challenging circumstance I just didn't have the right experience to do that as well as I would have liked. After a year or so, I asked to return to being a dev. Although I had definitely got rusty, I was surprised that it did come back quickly, plus I now had my experience of being a manager which gave me greater insights into  things like effectively communicating with other stakeholders, improving processes, refining requirements, etc. **I became a better developer.**

Secondly if one of your managees becomes better at managing, that's a good thing. You can delegate work to them, freeing up time for you to do other work. Maybe you can ask *your* manager for more responsiblity, maybe you can address issues you just haven't had time to do. Maybe you can even use it to keep your practice up for coding if you think that will help you as a manager.

Comment: Strongly agree with "trying out" management – if it doesn't work, you absolutely can go back to being an IC (of course assuming you didn't burn any bridges along the way). If you go back to IC, you will have learned more about yourself, which things you like and don't like about being a manager vs IC. All of this will help you find future roles you enjoy and are successful at.

Answer (score 2):

Your management promotes you to the leadership position because they **trust** that you can do a good job as a team lead or manager.

You should focus on your new role and do a great job there, and you will be fine. Being a good manager or team lead requires a lot of learning and practicing on the job. This skill will look great on your resume. Potential or future employers do value leadership skills.

In addition, you won't lose your ability to write code. If you need to, you can always take some times to review the coding practices, or data structures and algorithms, and do some coding homework problems at websites such as Leetcode, Hackerank, Codility, etc... So, you will be in great shape again as a programmer.

Don't worry that some of your reports may be better at writing code, and you will be fired because you may gradually lose your programing skills, and may not be good at leadership skills.

Comment: Somewhat philosophical, but I would not call move to management "promotion". Those two are not comparable even if it is beneficial for both positions to have experience with the other one. Like moving from meteorologist to fisherman is not considered promotion even if understanding weather is a useful skill for a fisherman.